# GUI text entry field is not being inserted in SQL database

Tags: python, sql, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to get the the inputs from the text entry fields into a table in SQL. However, when I insert the value, i see no result in my database. I get no errors, so I can't seem to find the error.

```
    #place the text entry fields

    global firstname
    global lastname
    global mark__
    global targetgrade

    firstname = Entry(self, width = 15, bg = "white")
    firstname.grid(row = 1, column=1, padx =5, pady = 5)

    lastname = Entry(self, width = 15, bg = "white")
    lastname.grid(row = 2, column=1, padx =5, pady = 5)

    mark__ = Entry(self, width = 15, bg = "white")
    mark__.grid(row = 3, column=1, padx =5, pady = 5)

    targetgrade = Entry(self, width = 15, bg = "white")
    targetgrade.grid(row = 4, column=1, padx =5, pady = 5)


    #Buttons to navigate


    button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Submit",
                        command = lambda:controller.show_frame(Submit) )

    button1.grid(row = 8 , column= 0)

    button2 = tk.Button(self, text = "Proceed",
                        command = lambda:controller.show_frame(ProceedToAnalysis) )
    button2.grid(row = 8, column = 1)
```

class Submit(tk.Frame):

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
    label = tk.Label(self, text = "Entry Submitted", font = LARGE_FONT)
    label.grid(pady = 10, padx = 10)

    button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Back to Home",
                        command = lambda:controller.show_frame(StartPage) )
    button1.grid(row = 8 , column= 0)

    button2 = tk.Button(self, text = "Proceed",
                        command = lambda:controller.show_frame(ProceedToAnalysis) )
    button2.grid(row = 8, column = 1)

    #inserting into database

    global firstname
    global lastname
    global mark__
    global targetgrade


    first = firstname.get()
    last= lastname.get()
    mark = mark__.get()
    target_grade = targetgrade.get()
    percentage =0
    grade = "Not yet declared"
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO class (first, last, mark, target_grade, percentage,grade) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)",(first,last,mark,target_grade,percentage,grade))
    conn.commit() #inserting the values in the database

    firstname.delete(0,END) # clearing the entry after the user has inputted data
    lastname.delete(0,END)
    mark__.delete(0,END)
    targetgrade.delete(0,END)
    firstname.focus_set()
```

I have done another version with less complex tkinter code with the same function and that seems to add into the database as it should. I did the same to this code,but it doesn't seem to work. Thank you in advance :)

```
#my previous code which works

def submit():
    first = firstname.get()
    last= lastname.get()
    mark = mark__.get()
    target_grade = targetgrade.get()
    percentage =0
    grade = "Not yet declared"
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO class (first, last, mark, target_grade, percentage,grade) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)",(first,last,mark,target_grade,percentage,grade))
    conn.commit() #inserting the values in the database
    ...
```

---

> Copy comment: I've tried
>
> ```
> def insertintosql(first,last,mark,target_grade,percentage,grade): 
>     with conn: 
>         cur.execute("INSERT INTO class (first, last, mark, target_grade, percentage,grade) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)",
>                     (first,last,mark,target_grade,percentage,grade)
>                     )
> ```

Comment: Doing `cur.execute(...` in `def __init__` will not work as `def __init__` is only executed **once** at instantiation. Move it to a **own** function, e.g. `def insert(...`.

Comment: i'm quite new to this, would you mind giving me a head start? I've tried          
def insertintosql(first,last,mark,target_grade,percentage,grade):
    with conn:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO class (first, last, mark, target_grade, percentage,grade) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)",(first,last,mark,target_grade,percentage,grade))

Comment: You are misguided, your problem is not the `SQL` statement. You didn't get how `OOP __init__` works. **Please confirm**: You click `.Button(self, text = "Submit",` and expect `.execute("INSERT ...` inside `def __init__` get executed.

Comment: Yes, that is how that should work

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look at changing the `conn.commit()` statement to a `cur.commit()` statement to see if that works.  If it does, it means your connection definition isn't leveraging autocommit, and you need to explicitly commit the insert.  Not sure what is different between this code and your more complex tkinter code, though.

Comment: Ok - no need to downtick the answer.  Just trying to help.  I've had situations where that works,  I've also had to do an explicit commit through a cur.execute command to the database.  You may want to try that, as well.

Comment: @MikeWalton OP has not enough reputation to downvote, so please don't assume they did. (I didn't vote)